# AngularJS - Dynamic validation in one input field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to be able to validate an input based on the following features:

There are two types of id's:

**Type A:**

12345678

45355678

53242234

**Type B:**

12345678-a1

32454353-a1

32454353-b1

As you can see the Type A has only numbers and the Type B has numbers followed by a hyphen then an alphabetic value and a number value (The sequence is strict).

So what I need to do is create the second regex in order to validate the Type B id but I don't know even how to start.

This is the directive:

```
app.directive('codeType', function() {
    return {
    scope: {
    codeType: '='
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
    function codeTypeA(text) {

    if (text) {
      var transformedInput
      if (!scope.codeType) {
        transformedInput = text.replace(/[^1-9]/g, '');
      } else {
        // Type B code regex
        transformedInput = text.replace(/[^1-9]/g, '');
      }


      if (transformedInput !== text) {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
        ngModelCtrl.$render();
      }
      return transformedInput;
    }
    return undefined;
  }
  ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(codeTypeA);
    }
    }
 });
```

[Plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/FjXkIJEAZ181efUq584c?p=preview)

***p.s.*** Is this a good way to validate two types of values? Is there a better solution?

Comment: It's as simple as this `/^\d+(?:-[a-z]\d)?$/`

Comment: Looks like there is no sequence, In need to start with number then a hyphen then a alphabetic value and a number.

Comment: This regex matches Type A or B. [/^\d+(?:-\[a-z\]\d)?$/](https://regex101.com/r/cEKDev/1)

Comment: Or, to know which one, `/^\d+(-[a-z]\d)?$/` if group 1 is not null, then its type B, else type A.